# In Django My form is resubmitting every time I refresh, I know I can solve this by redirecting it but i also want to pass data to my template

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, backend

This is my code in views

```
def pay(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name=request.POST.get('name')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        phone=request.POST.get('phone')
        course_name=request.POST.get('course_name')
        amount=int(request.POST.get('amount'))
        client = razorpay.Client(auth=('rzp_test_W8wCwbUqAGeqku','uETWabWBUeK53r70Qnz0Sg2Vknb'))
        payment = client.order.create({'amount':amount*100, 'currency':'INR', 'payment_capture':'1'})
        order = Order(course_name=course_name, name=name, email=email, phone=phone, amount=amount, payment_id=payment['id'])
        order.save()
        return render(request, 'pay.html',{'payment':payment})
        `I know I can solve this by redirecting it like this return redirect('womenlab:pay') but I also want to pass payment variable`

    return render(request, 'pay.html')
```

I do not want every time I refresh the page it get resumbitted, please help

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect after form is submitted to avoid form resubmission on refresh. Pass your payment ID to the redirect URL so that you could query order and fetch a payment you want to display:

```py
return redirect(reverse('womenlab:pay') + f"?payment_id={payment['id']}")
```

Then use `razorpay` client to fetch payment by ID and pass it to the template you want.